# Tansferring parent plus loan to a spouse

Tags: united-states, student-loan

Can I transfer a parent plus loan I took out for my daughter's undergraduate education to my wife who works for a non-profit agency and qualifies for a 10 year loan forgiveness program?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag?

Comment: Read the fine print of the loan agreement, but I suspect the time to think of that was when you were taking out the loan.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. The loan stays in the name of the person it was originally taken out under. You can try refinancing the loan in her name but you would lose certain borrower protections and I'm not entirely sure it's possible. Source: https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/types/loans/plus#transfer-loan